# ERROR: Input to reshape is a tensor with 2381440 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 200704

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to learn the CNN model in deep learning and I am using a `Cats-vs_Dogs` dataset to begin with. I am following a video tutorial and the steps are the same, although the dataset is different and all the other solutions have vastly varied code that I am not able to understand. Can someone tell me why I am going wrong here? Thanks

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import itertools
import os
import shutil
import random 
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Activation,Flatten,BatchNormalization,Conv2D,MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

train_batch=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
.flow_from_directory(directory='/content/Cat-vs-Dogs/train',target_size=(244,244),classes=['cats','dogs'],batch_size=10)

valid_batch=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
.flow_from_directory(directory='/content/Cat-vs-Dogs/valid',target_size=(244,244),classes=['cats','dogs'],batch_size=10)

test_batch=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
.flow_from_directory(directory='/content/Cat-vs-Dogs/test',target_size=(244,244),classes=['cats','dogs'],batch_size=10,shuffle=False)

model1=Sequential([
                   Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(224,224,3)),
                   MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2),
                   Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu', padding='same'),
                   MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2),
                   Flatten(),
                   Dense(units=2,activation='softmax')
 ])

model1.summary()
model1.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model1.fit(x=train_batch,validation_data=valid_batch,epochs=10,verbose=2)
```

The Error Output occurs like below
```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-3dd4821591bb> in <module>()
----> 1 model1.fit(x=train_batch,validation_data=valid_batch,epochs=10,verbose=2)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential_4/flatten_4/Reshape' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
      handler_func(fileobj, events)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 577, in _handle_events
      self._handle_recv()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 606, in _handle_recv
      self._run_callback(callback, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 556, in _run_callback
      callback(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
      return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
      handler(stream, idents, msg)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
      user_expressions, allow_stdin)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
      interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2828, in run_ast_nodes
      if self.run_code(code, result):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-76-3dd4821591bb>", line 1, in <module>
      model1.fit(x=train_batch,validation_data=valid_batch,epochs=10,verbose=2)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
      y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 374, in call
      return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 452, in call
      inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
      outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1096, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/flatten.py", line 96, in call
      return tf.reshape(inputs, flattened_shape)
Node: 'sequential_4/flatten_4/Reshape'
Input to reshape is a tensor with 2381440 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 200704
     [[{{node sequential_4/flatten_4/Reshape}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3624]
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the target size is (244, 244) and the input shape given in the model is (224, 224, 3). You can either change the target size to (224, 224) or change the input shape to (244, 244, 3).

Change the `input_shape` to `(244, 244, 3)`

```
Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu', padding='same',input_shape=(244, 244, 3)),
```

OR

Change the `target_size` to `(224, 224)` in train_batch, valid_batch and test_batch

```
train_batch=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
.flow_from_directory(directory='/content/Cat-vs-Dogs/train',target_size=(224, 224),classes=['cats','dogs'],batch_size=10)
```

Comment: Ok I am embarrased. I gave the wrong target size, it was supposed to be 224 and I did 244. Such a simple error but I continuosly scratched my head. Thank you very much for bringing it to myattention. It is working perfectly fine now. Although it istaking a lot of time. Is that normal?

Comment: Update: Got that done too. Used GPU as a hardware accelarator. Worked wonders.